# Arduino as Modbus RS485 slave using only 2 Digital pins

Tags: serial, rs485, modbus, max232

I want to use RX(0) and TX(1) Pins to make Arduino as an RS485 slave. To do this I am using MAX485 IC (Breakout board) https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX1487-MAX491.pdf

The problem here is that I don't have any other pins remaining to interface with the module in order to pull the DE/RE pin HIGH/LOW.

Can anyone suggest a way to do this without using one additional pin?

Comment: http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/tidubw6/tidubw6.pdf

Comment: @Majenko Thanks. I could definitely use the NA555.